# Displaying Snackbar from Utility class

Tags: java, android, android-snackbar

I am trying to display a `SnackBar` when an exception is thrown in my utility class.

**Utils.class**

```
    public class Utils {

  private static String LOG_TAG = Utils.class.getSimpleName();

  public static boolean showPercent = true;

  public static ArrayList quoteJsonToContentVals(String JSON){
    ArrayList<ContentProviderOperation> batchOperations = new ArrayList<>();
    JSONObject jsonObject = null;
    JSONArray resultsArray = null;
    try{
      jsonObject = new JSONObject(JSON);
      if (jsonObject != null && jsonObject.length() != 0){
        jsonObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("query");
        int count = Integer.parseInt(jsonObject.getString("count"));
        if (count == 1){
          jsonObject = jsonObject.getJSONObject("results")
              .getJSONObject("quote");
          batchOperations.add(buildBatchOperation(jsonObject));
        } else{
          resultsArray = jsonObject.getJSONObject("results").getJSONArray("quote");

          if (resultsArray != null && resultsArray.length() != 0){
            for (int i = 0; i < resultsArray.length(); i++){
              jsonObject = resultsArray.getJSONObject(i);
              batchOperations.add(buildBatchOperation(jsonObject));
            }
          }
        }
      }
    } catch (Exception e)
    {
      runError();  // <-- The method that displays the Snackbar
    }
    return batchOperations;
  }
```

And, now here is the method that tries to display the `SnackBar`:

```
  private static void runError()
  {

    Snackbar.make(this.findViewById(android.R.id.content), "OOPS that's an error :/", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
```

Now, the problem is : I am unable to get `context` to call `SnackBar`. I tried replacing `this` with:

- `getContext()`
- `getActivity()`
- `getApplicationContext()`

Since none of this did work, I tried creating an Application class to get context globally.

```
    public class StockMain extends Application
{
    private static StockMain instance;

    public static StockMain getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }

    public static Context getContext(){
        return instance;
        // or return instance.getApplicationContext();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        instance = this;
        super.onCreate();
    }
}
```

And tried changing, the method `runError()` to :

```
     private static void runError()
  {

    Snackbar.make(StockMain.getContext().findViewById(android.R.id.content), "OOPS that's an error :/", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
```

Unfortunately, that did not work as well! 
So, how to fix this issue?

Comment: Cant you store a static context or a View somewhere and use it?

Comment: Are you calling `quoteJsonToContentVals ` method in any Activity ?

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK Yes, I am calling it, and I am getting results, I am able to Log to get log in logcat when an exception occurs also,

Comment: @shaheen: Problem in current code is : `StockMain.getContext()` line return Application context and `Snackbar.make` required current visiable UI screen Context so if you are using Activity then pass `this` in quoteJsonToContentVals ` method to call `findViewById(android.R.id.content)`

Comment: alright, thanks @ρяσѕρєяK

Answer (score 0):

You can create **constructor** in your Util class and pass your Activity/Fragment's context to Util class. Like this:

public class Utils {
  Context mContext;

// Create constructor

```
public Utils(Context context)
{
mContext = context;
}
```

// Rest of your code
 }

and your **runError()**

```
private void runError()
  {
  Snackbar.make(mContext.findViewById(android.R.id.content), "OOPS that's an error :/", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
```

Comment: this will cause memory leaks, don't forget to null the context when you don't need it

Answer (score 0):

1. Try passing the `view` as parameter to your method as below-

   ```
   quoteJsonToContentVals(View view, String JSON)
   ```

where `view` can be any view that is referenced in `Activity`.

2. Then call `runError(view);`
3. Change method as below-

   ```
   private static void runError(View view) {
       Snackbar.make(view, "OOPS that's an error :/", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG).show();
   }
   ```